# RedHatLinux : Is it possible to programatically load the libcert.so shared object?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Good morning,RedHatLinux : Is it possible to programatily load the libcert.so shared object? On most RedHat Linux installation there exists a TCP-IP library called libcert.so which can installed using yum install XXXX  Hypothetically, suppose a software company wishes to build libcert.so independently and ship it with its other products, it would be necessary to programatically load libcert.so and then retrieve the function pointers to the public interface of the libcert library? Thank you.

Comment: @Nicholas Wilson, I just read the man dlopen page on RedHat Linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `dlopen` & `dlsym`. Here is a [How To](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/index.html).

Comment: Could you provide some sample code? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Frank - take your time :). Anyway - this is the simplest example in the link - http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html#DL-LIBRARY-EXAMPLE